# How to move messenger bot right to left in custom website?

Tags: messenger

I have this code for my chatbot. It's showing **by default right-bottom on my website**. But I want it **on the left-bottom side**. I am unable to do it. Can anyone give me the code ?

**My Code :**

```
<!-- Load Facebook SDK for JavaScript -->
<div id="fb-root"></div>

<script>
  window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
    FB.init({
      xfbml            : true,
      version          : 'v3.2'
    });
  };

  (function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = 'https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/sdk/xfbml.customerchat.js';
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>

<!-- Your customer chat code -->
<div class="fb-customerchat"
  attribution=setup_tool
  page_id="384557738790994">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The best way would be to use the `fb-customerchat` class to style the chat box.

You would put the styles into your css file, or if you don't have one inside a `style` element.

```
<style>
 .fb-customerchat { 
     position: absolute;
     left: 0;
     bottom: 0;
 };
</style>
```

at the top of your html file.

Depending on the hierarchy of the styles that already exist you may need to use `left: 0 !important;` instead.

Answer (score 1):

```css
 .bottom-left {
          position: fixed;
          bottom: 0;
          left: 0;
        }

        .alert {
          border: 2px solid red;
          background: white;
          font-weight: bold;
          padding: 1em;
        }
```

```html
        <div class="bottom-left alert">
          Look at me!
        </div>

        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit..</p>

        <p>Sed vel dolor lectus. Nulla sed blandit lacus. </p>

        <p>Donec sagittis, dolor sed fermentum dapibus, justo ipsum porttitor purus, sed fermentum mi nulla non lorem.</p>
```

This will solve your problem

Answer (score 1):

You can take left side the popup section by follow this simple css tricks. Add the following css code then check it by refresh your browser by ctrt+F5

```
<style>
 .fb_dialog { 
     left: 18pt;
 };

  iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_in_v2{
     left:36pt!important;
  }

  iframe.fb_customer_chat_bounce_out_v2{
     left:36pt!important;
  }
</style>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<style>
 .fb_dialog { 
     left: 18pt;
 };
</style>
```

Its work for me. By the way thanks to everyone.

Answer (score 0):

This is full customised facebook chatbot and really easy to use

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    (function () {
        var options = {

            facebook: "your_facebook_page_id", // Facebook page ID like 598880463493066         

            call_to_action: "Your_message", // Call to action that user seen like "Message us"

            position: "left", // Position may be 'right' or 'left'
        };

        var proto = document.location.protocol, host = "getbutton.io", url = proto + "//static." + host;
        var s = document.createElement('script'); s.type = 'text/javascript'; s.async = true; s.src = url + '/widget-send-button/js/init.js';
        s.onload = function () { WhWidgetSendButton.init(host, proto, options); };
        var x = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0]; 
        x.parentNode.insertBefore(s, x);
    })();
</script>
```